# Basic Plotting Question/ How do I format my axis?

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I have made my own data set for a student project I'm working on and I am attempting to plot a graph to show employment outcomes, the number employed, in different regions. I am new to Rstudio/data in general and a technophobe! I am struggling to get my Y axis to show the numbers as normal numbers, not exponential notation (if that's what it's called 6e+04 etc?)

Further to this, the X axis is only choosing certain regions to display, more if I expand it. How can I fix this to show all the regions?

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

I have tried using `ylim=c(ymin=0, ymax=100000)` in the plot. (Info, max value for employed is just below 100000). But this made no change to the plot.

```
employment.region$Region<- factor(employment.region$Employed, labels=c("North East","North West","Yorkshire","East Midlands","West Midlands","East of England","London","South East","South West","Wales","Scotland"))

plot(employment.region$Region,employment.region$Employed, ylim=c(ymin=0, ymax=100000), frame= FALSE)

AND 

plot(employment.region$Employed~employment.region$Region, ylim=c(ymin=0, ymax=100000))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you, will look at this and use the correct format in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot without a `y` axis, then set the tick marks and the axis labels by hand. This is why `yticks` and `yaxis_labs` are defined. 
Then plot, with `las = 2` to have the axis' annotations perpendicular to the axis.

```
yticks <- seq(0, 100000, by = 2e4)
yaxis_labs <- formatC(yticks, digits = 6)

old_par <- par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)

plot(employment.region$Region, employment.region$Employed, 
     ylim=c(ymin=0, ymax=100000), frame= FALSE, las = 2, yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = yticks, labels = yaxis_labs, las = 2)

par(old_par)
```

Comment: this probably overwrites old `par` with new `par`, though

Comment: @jay.sf Why? I save `old_par`, plot and reset to the original value. Function `par` returns the values that were effective *before* the call.

Comment: @jay.sf In the call `par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)`

Comment: Ah great, so `par` actually is assigned and executed as well, didn't realize that feature so far! Thx

Comment: Thanks Rui! Just trying to understand fully so I can replicate in the future. Why is old_par and a new par used?

Comment: @abbiewood To make room for the rotated x axis labels. Try the other code instructions and see the result.